# Difference between static and normal function inside a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class

I have defined my class in this manner

```
class className {
  constructor() {

  }

  static myStaticFunction() {
    console.log("myStaticFunction")
  }

  normalFunction() {
    console.log("normalFunction")
  }
}

module.exports = className
```

I know `normalFunction` can be called using `instance` whereas static function can be called without the `instance`.
But I need to know what is the difference between above two function declaration?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

When a function is called from the class itself it is called a `static` function where as the normal function is called on the instance of the class

For example

```
class className {
  constructor() {}

  static myStaticFunction() {
    console.log("myStaticFunction")
  }

  normalFunction() {
    myStaticFunction() // here myStaticFunction is called from same class
    console.log("normalFunction")
  }
}

module.exports = className
```

In some other js file

```
import * as class1 from './class';
class className2 {
      constructor() {}

        someFunction() {
        class1 .normalFunction(); //calling class function
        console.log("normalFunction")
      }
    }

    module.exports = className2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Static function -** is not entitled to any object instance. Which means that function is accessible with out instance and it also cannnot access any instance data. Basically it helps to expose functionality which kind of util.

> As MDN describes it, “Static methods are called without instantiating
>   their class and are also not callable when the class is instantiated.
>   Static methods are often used to create utility functions for an
>   application.” In other words, static methods have no access to data
>   stored in specific objects.

Example : `Math.Sqrt(val) -` is util function.

And Static function must need be pure functions, that doesnt modify the object data and provides utility.

so here how it works

```
class className {
  instanceCounter = 0;
  staticCounter = 0;
  constructor() {

  }

  static myStaticFunction() {
    this.staticCounter++;
    console.log("myStaticFunction"+ staticCounter);
  }

  normalFunction() {
    this.instanceCounter++;
    console.log("normalFunction" + instanceCounter);
  }
}
```

now if i make call

```
   //for static   
   className.myStaticFunction();//print 1
   className.myStaticFunction();//print 2

   //for instace 
   new className().normalFunction();//print 1
   new className().normalFunction();//print 1
```